# Is this a secure login system for admin panel?

Tags: php, html, security, authentication, admin

This is the code for my website's admin page login

```
<?php
//simple PHP login script using Session
//start the session * this is important
session_start();

//login script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'login'){

//give your login credentials here
if($_REQUEST['uname'] == 'my_name' && $_REQUEST['pass'] == 'my_password')
$_SESSION['login_user'] = 1;
else
$_SESSION['login_msg'] = 1;
}

//get the page name where to redirect
if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
$pagename = $_REQUEST['pagename'];

//logout script
if(isset($_REQUEST['ch']) && $_REQUEST['ch'] == 'logout'){
unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
header('Location:login.php');
}
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
if(isset($_REQUEST['pagename']))
header('Location:'.$pagename.'.php');
else
header('Location:admin.php');
}else{
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="all" />


</head>
<body>

<form name="login_form" method="post" action="">
<h2 align="center"><strong>Admin Login</strong></h2>

<input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">

<td colspan="2" align="center">
<p style="color:red;">
<?php
//display the error msg if the login credentials are wrong!
if(isset($_SESSION['login_msg'])){
echo 'Wrong username and password !';
unset($_SESSION['login_msg']);
}
?>
</p>

<div align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login"></div>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="ch" value="login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I copied this from a website so i'm not really sure how safe it is. And I'm also not so good with php.

is this safe to use or is it easy to hack?
if it's not can anyone tell me what is the best none-MySQL login system?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: Oh... I didn't know that there is a website for that.

Comment: there's a website for EVERYTHING

Comment: I take it you're not using a database?  How important is security and the password to you?  Storing the password in plain text isn't a very good idea.  You should also get in the habit of validating all user input, it is dangerous to insert user input directly into a code whether it be SQL, Javascript, or PHP.

Comment: if you just want a one or couple person protection for a directory Apache Basic authentication is the obvious approach, set up takes less than a minute, no need to edit any code. I often use it on my small sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_REQUEST, by default, contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

But it's only a default, which depends on variables_order ; and not sure you want to work with cookies.

If I had to choose, I would probably not use $_REQUEST, and I would choose $_GET or $_POST -- depending on what my application should do (i.e. one or the other, but not both) : generally speaking :

You should use $_GET when someone is requesting data from your application.
And you should use $_POST when someone is pushing (inserting or updating ; or deleting) data to your application.
Either way, there will not be much of a difference about performances : the difference will be negligible, compared to what the rest of your script will do.

Also, you may need to check for XSS and CSRF. However, it really depends on the application requirements.
I hate to be blunt, but IMHO this does not look like a secure or practical login block of code.
Also, may I ask why are you not planning on using a DB? Using stored plain text passwords is not very secure at all.

The below applies if you plan on using a DB.
Your code does not check against a db for multiple users. It mainly checks against a stored password. Therefore, the application practicality would be very limited unless you use a db to support multiple users.
Also, if you are going to use a db to store and retrieve values you need to make sure the user inputs a protected against SQL injections. Plus it would be wise to encrypt the passwords by using md5,salt,sha1 or a combination. Many guys use an encryption combination.